# Can't use malloc twice in a function

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to write a simple HTTP server.
I wrote a simple function called '`handleConnection`' to handle incoming connection.
I use two malloc functions. First one is to receive the GET header and second one is to extract the path from GET header and second one cause `malloc(): corrupted top size\nAborted` error.
Here is the code:

```
int handleConnection(int sockfd)
{
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    socklen_t clientLength = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    int new_sockfd;
    
    new_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &clientLength);
        
    // receive get header
    int getHeaderSize = 0;
    char *getHeader = malloc(getHeaderSize);
    char tempBuffer;
    
    // stop receiving while loop when matchedTerminators is equal to 2
    int matchedTerminators = 0;
    char terminators[2] = {'\r', '\n'};
    
    // receiving while loop
    while(matchedTerminators != 2)
    {
        recv(new_sockfd, (void *)&tempBuffer, 1, 0);
                        
        if(tempBuffer == terminators[0] || tempBuffer == terminators[1])
            matchedTerminators++;           
        else
        {
            matchedTerminators = 0;
            getHeaderSize++;
            strcat(getHeader, &tempBuffer);
        }
    }
    // If already received the get header
      
    printf("%s\n", getHeader);
    
    // extract the path(/) from get header
    int pathSize = 0; // this value might increase later
    char* path = malloc(pathSize); // when pathSize is increaced this malloc function cause error
    
    /*
        Code to extract the path from get header
    */
    
    // free malloc
    free(path);
    free(getHeader);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Both of your `malloc` calls are allocating a zero-sized memory block. You need to determine the parameter sizes *before* calling the allocator.

Comment: But I increase getHeaderSize and pathSize in while loops

Comment: @SwamHtetAung: Which has no effect on what you've allocated.  There's no magic connection between those variables and the allocated memory block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you allocate 0 bytes of memory:

```
int getHeaderSize = 0;
char *getHeader = malloc(getHeaderSize);
```

Here you try and store a byte of data in the 0 bytes you allocated:

```
        strcat(getHeader, &tempBuffer);
```

Bonus: `strcat` only works on null-terminated strings, and you never tried to make getHeader into a null-terminated string.

You may know this already, but it's a common beginner mistake: the computer does things in the order you tell it to, unless otherwise indicated. It does *not* do all the things at once. It does not go back and redo things it already did (unless you tell it to). If you do `malloc(getHeaderSize)` and `getHeaderSize` is 0, it allocates 0 bytes of memory. If you change `getHeaderSize` to 100 after that, you still allocated 0 bytes of memory, because the computer doesn't time-travel.

Comment: Thanks I use realloc and it solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
int getHeaderSize = 0;
char *getHeader = malloc(getHeaderSize);
// ...
int pathSize = 0;
char* path = malloc(pathSize);
```

The two `molloc` calls allocate memory for **0 byte**, so when you try to access some value such as `path[0]`, it must be out of the memory range. And you will get the error `malloc(): corrupted top size` which means you have wrongly accessed memory.

Comment: This answer would be better without the last sentence.